# FPDF Background Images: what size for a good A4 background

Tags: php, background, fpdf

I've been struggling for a while now trying to add a good looking background to my PDF created using the FPDF class. I tried a photoshop document based on international A4 paper, but this was too big. Also converting it from 300dpi to 72dpi (as it's said in the manual) is not good, it just looks pixelated now.

I found various settings on the net (~1062px width), but that's too wide and when testing with something that should match up just creates a pixelated version instead of a good background image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 600px seems a correct width to fit the PDF.. but the tekst is just awfull..

Comment: They do have a limited quality as I remember noticing this myself. You can actually gives measurements in mm (millimeters) if you want the full width that should be 210mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that 'dpi' is just a conversion factor. it's not a measurement in-and-of-itself. The size of the background image will depend on what kind of medium you're planning on the PDF being displayed on.

If it's intended for screen display, which is generally 72-100dpi (let's split the difference and go with 86dpi). A4 paper is 210x297mm, or 8.27x11.7 inches, which means you need a background image of 711x1006 so it wouldn't get scaled.

If you're going for a 300dpi target, which is your average generic laser printer, then you'd need 2481x3510, and for 600dpi target, double again to 4962x7020

Comment: Learn something new every day!

Comment: thanks, let me try using the 711x1006. Will let you know in a minute.

Comment: 711 is too big, the one I used to have was good, which is 611px. But the quality is just poor so I guess the problem lies with FPDF and not with the dimensions. See for yourself: `http://www.mocon-showtechniek.nl/cpanel/pakbon.php` is the created PDF from this source `http://www.mocon-showtechniek.nl/cpanel/images/bg.png`

Comment: They look about equivalent to me here. Of course, you've got a pretty small grey font antialiased against a white background, so your original image is already pretty hard to read.

Comment: True, but if I make the image larger the text on the PDF get's more pixelated aswell and I can clearly see the large 'M' on the background stretching to far horizontally.

Comment: Current version works fine, in PDF it doesn't look good, but printing the PDF gives a pretty good result. Since it's for printing purposes only this is close enough to 'perfection'. Thanks for the information Marc!